# Direct mapping for Equation of line from point and angle with Y

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

I want to compute the coefficients of line $Ax+By+C=0$ given a point $x_0,y_0$ and angle $r$ the line makes with positive $y$ direction. Any direct mapping would be more heloful

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is the angle made with the positive $y$ direction, then $\frac{\pi}{2}+r$ is the angle made with the positive $x$ direction.

The slope of the line is the tangent of the angle made with the positive $x$ direction (drawing a diagram makes this clear), so the slope is $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+r)$.

Now you have a point and a slope; use point-slope formula for a line to finish.

$y-y_0=(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+r))(x-x_0)$

$(-\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+r))x+y+((\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+r))x_0-y_0)=0$